# adding an event to select box through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to add a new event to the select box, i had seen many jquery codes here on stackoverflow, but the one does not seems what i am trying to do:

here is my code try:

```
if ($("#Filters").find("select[multiple='multiple']").length != 0){ 
  $("#Filters").find('select[name="myselect"]').removeAttr('onChange');
  $("#Filters").find('select[name="myselect"]').attr('onChange','onmultipleoptions');               
}
```

I want to remove the onchange and then add again the onchange with new function called as `onmultipleoptions()`..

Guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error when creating the new `onChange`.

Change

```
.attr('onChange','onmultipleoptions')
```

to:

```
.attr('onChange','onmultipleoptions()')
```

You could accomplish binding the new event handler using jQuery `.change(onmultipleoptions)` or `.on('change',onmultipleoptions)` instead of replacing the attribute

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r68ob0t0/)**</kbd>

Comment: Yup, way better using jQuery event listeners.